# Activity or Fragment or?

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, android-dialog

I have the the following Activity LinearLayout.

```
<!-- Main LinearLayout -->
<LinearLayout
   ...
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <!-- Inner LinearLayout -->
   <LinearLayout... />

   <!-- Fragment holding Google Map Fragment -->
   <fragment android:name=".MainMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <!-- Inner LinearLayout -->
   <LinearLayout... />  

</LinearLayout/>
```

I have some **Google Map Markers** displayed in the **MainMapFragment** showing that around that location there are some specific related business to look into.

Once a User clicks on any of those Markers on the Map... I need to display a LIST of all those  Business associated to that MARKER and allow the User to Tag/Mark the business as FAVORITE or NOT.

I have everything done in relation to the Google Map, Markers, InfoWindow, etc... however... I would like to know what should be a good way/design/layout to DISPLAY the Business List (ListView is ok) detail information and allow the User to MARK AS FAVORITE any of the business in the list using a REGULAR BUTTON (or TOGGLE BUTTON) display within the Business Information Details.

Although I already thought on some choices (see below), I am not sure which one to go for it.

- Launch a new Activity, once back (new activity finished) update the information within the Map, Markers, etc.
- Add a new Fragment to the current Layout and SWITCH (hide/show) between the one with the Map and the one with the Business Information.
- A Modal Dialog (DialogInterface, AlertDialog, etc)

Once again I am not sure where to go and so my question... what will be a good design/model to approach this request?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english, i think that you should use an activity, If I understood correctly on click event you should display details of the related place, a good habit of mobile programming is to display details in other activity with the back button in the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up extending **DialogFragment**, not only works OK but also allowed me to work with anything in a custom/complex layout inside the Dialog.